# Should I still display splash screens for middleware that has been discontinued?

Tags: licensing

Usually, you would include splash logos at the beginning of a game to credit various middleware that you've used. Say the company has dissolved or for open source the supporting group has simply moved on and declared the project over. In the hypothetical situation where a middleware project has been discontinued and you still have the legal right to use it, wouldn't you still include the logo for that project at the beginning?

Only concerned with the opening splashes, since I'm pretty sure it would be polite to credit the individuals who worked on that piece in the text credits or at the end.

Comment: Good question, but as usual seeking legal advice on the Internet is not advisable. Personally I'd just keep including it.

Comment: I would think it would be polite to continue showing the splash screens too, personally.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thinking as well. I know I'd want to see my project's logo, even if it was something I no longer work on, whether it's still supported or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of splash screens depends on the agreements you have (or have accepted by using the software) with a specific company. This will vary from software to software and must be researched for each piece of software you use. Just because the software is no longer being worked on doesn't mean there are no longer legal requirements for its use.

You can remain on the safe side and include it now it you were supposed to include it before. If you don't want to show it anymore, you'll have to do the research for the specific technology you're using.